# Meteor iron-router : cancel a route

Tags: javascript, meteor, router

Some routes in my application are game and I want to implement a confirmation process when the user is about to leave a runing game.

Is there a way to "stop" the router ?.

I tried that :

```
Router.configure({

    onBeforeRun: function() {
        Router.stop();
    }
});
```

Bu it destroys evrything.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use something like this? (I haven't used Iron-Router myself yet)
Basically just catching the links click event, and throwing a confirm dialog. If they click yes it will run the router's go method which triggers the route change, otherwise the click is ignored

***edit** updates code to use original href value instead*

```
Meteor.templateName.events({
  'click .someLink': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (game.isRunning && confirm('are you sure you want to leave?') ) {
      // Router.go('routeName');  // edit, see comment below
      Router.url(e.target.href);
    }     

  }
});
```

Comment: that would work, but this mean i cannot use the `{{link-to}}` helper ; which is one of the basic nice utilities in iron-router

Comment: Good point. I updated the code above to use their url method, which looks like it navigated to the url you pass it to. Alternatively you might be able to strip out that and just place the `e.preventDefault()` inside the if statement. (not sure offhand)

Comment: Oh I saw how to use your answer :) I edit your code a little bit

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but just solved it. Here is my solution :

```
Router.route('/myPath', {
    unload: function (e, obj) {
        if(Session.get("hasChanged")){
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away ?")) {
                // Go and do some action
            }else{
                // Redirect to itself : nothing happend
                this.redirect('/myPath');
           }
        }
    }
}
```